# Bash alias --> Python 2.7 to Python 3.3

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, python-3.3

I am trying to make Python 3.4.2 the default in Linux (currently it is 2.7.6). I am not very knowledgeable on this stuff, but I have read in several places online that you can simply put an alias in the `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_aliases` file like this:

```
alias python='python3'
```

I don't have either the `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_aliases` file . . . I am assuming you can just create them. I have done that, but the alias doesn't seem to be working. Am I missing something? Do you need the shebang at the beginning of the file? I have tried it both ways.

Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: Did you remember to `source` the files you created (or close your terminals and re-open them)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**DON'T DO IT!**

Some linux utilities depend on `python2.x` currently. It will probably break your system if you make that change since `python3.x` is not backward compatible with `python2.x`. Unless you are fully aware of the consequences, don't do it!

Similar question is asked here : https://askubuntu.com/questions/103469/how-do-i-change-my-pythonpath-to-make-3-2-my-default-python-instead-of-2-7-2

Comment: Yes, never change this. Use the system Python for your operating system or install the desired version alongside it. Never alias it.

Comment: Thanks for this. Sorry, I see this was a year ago and somehow I never saw your answer.

Comment: @laurenll you can accept as an answer if you think it is the right one.

Comment: how do you ``un-alias``? I removed ``alias python = 'python3'`` from the ``.bash_profile``, restarted the terminal, but the ``which python`` is still v3.

Comment: Creating an alias in your personal account isn't going to affect any system services. As long as you don't physically remove or replace a system-installed version, you're fine.

Answer (score 0):

In a bash file the following will not work:

> alias python='python3'

The alias syntax is not available in sh script execution. In order to execute python commands with bash that work on both python and python3. I wrote a function that checks if python3 or python is available and then pass on the function argument to that local installation of python.

The example code is taken from a script that runs on machines that sometimes do not have python but do have python3 installed.

This code was tested on Ubuntu 18 and 16 (Windows Subsystem Linux 2).

```
#!/bin/bash
function local_python() {
  _python=$(which python)
  _python3=$(which python3)
  python=${_python3:-_python}
}

curl "http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp" \
  -X GET \
  -H "Accept: application/json" |
  local_python "import sys, json; print(json.loads(sys.stdin.read())['geoplugin_request'])"
```

The above code can be copied and pasted into an example.sh file and should (as long as url is available) return with your IP address.

Comment: Why do you think alases are not available in Bash? I certainly recommend functions over aliases for basically everything; but aliases are available in interactive sessions just fine.

Comment: Also, the [useless use of `echo`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo) is something you want to avoid.